# Как задать z-index элементу в Owl-carousel?

Tags: owl-carousel

Хочу изменить z-index стрелок, чтобы при наведении они выходили вперед на фоне градиента, но не могу понять как это сделать. В .owl-prev и .owl-next стрелка обозначена элементом с id='text', но при попытке манипуляции со стилями этого элемента ничего не получилось. Как сделать так, чтобы стрелки все же оказывались поверх фона и меняли цвет на белый?

Сайт tempesv0.beget.tech
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.reviews {
  text-align: center;
}
.reviews .wrapper {
  padding: 0 30px !important;
}
.reviews .content p {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.reviews-block {
  background-color: #f7fafc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  height: 300px;
}
.reviews-block:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
.reviews-text {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}
.reviews-user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.reviews-user img {
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 80px !important;
  border-radius: 100% !important;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.reviews-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
.reviews-info .name {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #222222;
}
.reviews-info .inc {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial';
}
.reviews .owl-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100% ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
.reviews .owl-prev {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}
.reviews .owl-next {
  transform: translateX(70px);
}
.reviews .owl-prev,
.reviews .owl-next {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-size: 25px !important;
  font-weight: 800 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.reviews .owl-prev:after,
.reviews .owl-next:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fd712c 0%, #f21780 100%);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.reviews .owl-prev:hover:after,
.reviews .owl-next:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="reviews">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>What our customers are saying</h3>
                <p>Everyone’s reasons for learning user interface design are different. If you’re already a developer, or a PM, or a UX designer, why develop this totally separate skill?</p>

                <div class=" wrapper owl-carousel reviews-slider">
                    <div class="reviews-block">
                        <p class="reviews-text">The JustLanded for WordPress theme is great, super easy to use and to customize and the support is just awesome: super fast and reliable.</p>
                        
                        <div class="reviews-user">
                            <img src="img/rew/1.jpg" alt="1">
                            
                            <div class="reviews-info">
                                <span class="name">Alexandra Bullock</span>
                                <span class="inc">Apple Inc.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="reviews-block">
                        <p class="reviews-text">Very happy with the theme and incredibly easy to configure, well done! I cannot emphasize how awesome this theme and developer support are.</p>
                        
                        <div class="reviews-user">
                            <img src="img/rew/2.jpg" alt="2">
                            
                            <div class="reviews-info">
                                <span class="name">Gary Sebastian</span>
                                <span class="inc">Apple Inc.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="reviews-block">
                        <p class="reviews-text">Definitely a great theme and the support team are fantastic. Customer support is numero uno and ShapingRain have got this spot on. Cheers guys.</p>
                        
                        <div class="reviews-user">
                            <img src="img/rew/3.jpg" alt="3">
                            
                            <div class="reviews-info">
                                <span class="name">Samantha Bilbau</span>
                                <span class="inc">Apple Inc.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="reviews-block">
                        <p class="reviews-text">Very happy with the theme and incredibly easy to configure, well done! I cannot emphasize how awesome this theme and developer support are.</p>
                        
                        <div class="reviews-user">
                            <img src="img/rew/4.jpg" alt="4">
                            
                            <div class="reviews-info">
                                <span class="name">Ren Chai</span>
                                <span class="inc">Apple Inc.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас элемент .owl-prev:after показывается поверх стрелки, значит нужно изменить его z-index на "-1", тем самым стрелка будет поверх фона.

```
.reviews .owl-prev:after,
.reviews .owl-next:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fd712c 0%, #f21780 100%);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1; /*тут с "2" на "-1"*/
}
```

Далее изменяем цвет стрелки, в данном случае нужно добавить новое правило:

```
.owl-prev:hover, .owl-next:hover
{
    color: white !important;
}
```